# Failed to Make a Connection from Airflow to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I want to make a connection from Airflow to Google Cloud. I have made a service account in Google Cloud, downloaded the JSON file, and saved the JSON file inside the docker.

I am following this https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections documentation, but it returns the following error:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x7f765dfbeb10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No
> route to host'))
> [image]

Am I doing something wrong or is there an update on the documentation?

Nb:

1. I use Apache Airflow 2.4.2
2. I already tested the service account JSON file and it works perfectly to upload data using Python

Comment: Your Airflow is used from a Docker container or directly with Cloud Composer ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun Docker container

Answer (score 0):

You can create a connection to `Google Cloud` from `Airflow` webserver admin menu. In this menu you can pass the Service Account key file path.

[image]

In this picture, the `keyfile Path` is `/usr/local/airflow/dags/gcp.json`.

Beforehand you need to mount your key file as a volume in your `Docker` container with the previous path.

You can also directly copy the key json content in the Airflow connection, in the `keyfile Json` field :

[image]

You can check from these following links :

[Airflow-connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html)

[Airflow-with-google-cloud](https://junjiejiang94.medium.com/get-started-with-airflow-google-cloud-platform-docker-a21c46e0f797)

[Airflow-composer-managing-connections](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections)

Comment: In the question picture, I already try to make a connection in the Airflow webserver admin menu. I also already mounted the JSON file in the docker and passed the file path in **Keyfile Path**. The JSON file has already been detected.

Comment: Have you also tried with directly the json key content for testing purpose ? It corresponding to keyfile json field in the form

Comment: I tried, but the same error still appear. I think there is nothing wrong with the service account JSON file because I have tested uploading files with Python and it works.